# Steam missing package libcurl3.7.34 on ubuntu 14.04 64bit?

Tags: software-installation, steam

Here is my problem: I'm trying to install steam and I got this error:

```
sudo apt-get install steam-launcher

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
steam-launcher : Depends: curl
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I try to install curl and i got this:

```
sudo apt-get install curl

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
curl : Depends: libcurl3 (= 7.34.0-1ubuntu1) but 7.35.0-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have the latest version of libcurl3 (7.35).

So how can I install an old version of libcurl3 (7.34)?

I searched [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) but have not found anything.